# Can I put my cast iron pan with wood handle in the oven?

Tags: oven, pan, skillet

Can I put my cast iron pan with wood handle in the oven? [This is what it looks like](http://d2ydh70d4b5xgv.cloudfront.net/images/f/a/le-creuset-28-cast-iron-skillet-orange-flame-enamel-teak-wood-handle-843b61ad24ce0866282b05519557009f.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've decided to buy a cast iron only pan to make sure I would not degraded the other pan.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would not put it in the oven.  You may be able to get away with it if you are not broiling anything for an extended period of time, but heat does not play nice with wood and after extended use I would expect the wood on the handle to blacken or even crack.

Answer (score 4):

When I have a fry pan with "other" material handle and want to put it in the oven I wrap it in 3-4 layers of tin foil first and no problem. Usually the oven isn't any higher than 375 degrees Fahrenheit.  Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I was thinking the same as you but I finally decided not to do it since this is a le creuset pan that belonged to my mother.